# handling 400 and 503 in xmlhttprequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax, event-handling, xmlhttprequest

I'm using XmlHttpRequest to call a service from a service library.  I need to handle errors such as 400 (Bad Request) and 503 (Internal Server Error).  It looks like XmlHttpRequest only returns a status of 200 (OK) or 404 (Page not Found):

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp

So how could I code my XmlHttpRequest routine to handle 400 and 503 errors? Also, if I have my XmlHttpRequest wrapped in a js module that is consumed by downstream clients then what would be a good modular design to allow downstream clients to hook into error events such as 400/503 status codes in order to downstream clients to implement their own specific error handling?

Comment: [This is why you shouldn't trust w3schools.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/status) That status code can be any HTTP status code. Not just the two they've listed.

Comment: ok so if xmlhttp.status != 200 then should I generally be able to get error details/text from xmlhttp.responseText?

Comment: or should I include info from xmlhttp.responseText as well as xmlhttp.responseText?

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out? You ought to be able to get information from `responseText` and `statusText`.

Comment: which xhr properties are available/populated in the onerror event handler?